# Grep a text file recursively to filter absolute paths

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file with lots of filepaths in it. I need to extract all directories (exclude filenames and extensions) and make a new text file out of it.
Directory depth may vary, disk drive label may vary also.

I need to keep the duplicates!!!

Not sure which route to take since directory depth varies greatly: awk, sed, grep

```
Input (sample.txt):
C:\lolz\yoloz\thisisit.txt
D:\Windows\Programs\Others\Hell\gate.exe
D:\Windows\Programs\Others\Hell\rain.exe
E:\Auto\Plane\Boat\transport.ini

Expected output:
C:\lolz\yoloz
D:\Windows\Programs\Others\Hell
D:\Windows\Programs\Others\Hell
E:\Auto\Plane\Boat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This short one-line works for your current example:

```
sed 's/\\[^\\]\+$//' sample.txt
```

Comment: @SyntycheAckerley you should accept the most useful answer.

Comment: You should mention that that requires GNU sed for `\+` or just use `*` instead for portability to all seds.

Comment: @yoga it is a very fundamental regex, which part do you have problem to understand?

Comment: @yoga I cannot explain all the regex sorry, or I am writing a tutorial. But you can check this, there are examples: https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Comment: Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
grep -o '[A-Z]\:[\\a-zA-Z0-9]*\\' sample.txt | sort  | uniq
```

Explanation:
Start with a drive letter: `[A-Z]`, followed by a colon `\:`
Next to that, a list of backslashes, letters and digits `[\\a-zA-Z0-9]*`
It needs to end with a backslash, in order to get the directory `\\`

Apparently, in order to this to work, you need singles quotes.

`grep -o` is for filtering the grep output.

The `sort | uniq` is for removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Or a pure bash solution without external tool

```
while read -r line || [[ ${line} ]]; do
  [[ ${line} =~ (.*)\\[^\\]* ]]
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/.{9}$/,"")sub(/\\t.?../,"")}1' file

C:\lolz\yoloz
D:\Windows\Programs\Others\Hell
D:\Windows\Programs\Others\Hell
E:\Auto\Plane\Boat
```